# substitution in Beltrami identity [solved]

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, curves, substitution, euler-lagrange-equation

**This has been solved** :was an overwrite error

substitution in beltrami identity:
 $$F(y,y')= \sqrt{\frac{1+y'^2}{2gy}}$$
$$\frac{\partial F}{\partial y'} = \frac{y'^2}{\sqrt{1+y'^2}\sqrt{2gy}}$$

Beltrami identity:$$F-y'\frac{\partial F}{\partial y'} = C$$

My answer: $\sqrt{\frac{1+y'^2 }{2gy}} -\frac{y'^2}{\sqrt{1+y'^2}\sqrt{2gy}}=C$
simplifying gives:
$\frac{1}{\sqrt{y(y'^2+1)}}=C\sqrt{2g}$

final simplifying answer :
$$y(1+y'^2)=\frac{1}{2gC^2}=2R$$
<s>i am clearly substituting wrong, can someone help?</s> has been resolved thx :)

Comment: Are you sure about $\frac{\partial F}{\partial y'}$?

Comment: @ancientmathematician thnx solved it, the y' had to be y'^2, stupid error while writing the equation over and over.

Comment: It was $(y')^2$ in $F$, OK, but it is just numerator $y'$ in the partial derivative.